# How to Watson assistant differentiate between different users

Tags: javascript, api, watson, watson-assistant

I have created a chatbot using Watson assistant. I am using it through API calls.

Suppose there are two different persons who want to use my chatbot at the same time. then what I have to do in order to make Watson understand that two different persons are sending the requests.

if there are any extra parameters which can be included to handle this problem? if yes, please mention.

```js
//var objDiv = document.getElementById("chatbotid");
//objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
document.querySelector("#input").addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (key === 13) { //Enter button
    var input = document.getElementById("input").value; //storing input value
    document.getElementById("input").value = "";
    TempChatInput = document.getElementById("chatbot");
    TempChatInput.innerHTML += "user: " + input + "<br/><br/>";
    //document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = input;
    output(input);
  }
});

function output(input) {
  //var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var newData = "{\"input\": {\"text\":" + "\"" + input + "\"" + "}}";
  //var input = $('input').val();
  var dataText;
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1/workspaces/myWorkspaceID/message?version=2018-02-16",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      //xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic" + btoa(username + ":" + password));
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("my username" + ":" + "my password"));
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    processData: false,
    //data: "{\"input\": {\"text\": \"location\"}}",
    data: newData,
    success: function(data) {
      dataText = data["output"]["text"];
      //console.log(dataText);
      TempChat = document.getElementById("chatbot");
      TempChat.innerHTML += "Chatbot: " + dataText + "<br/><br/>";
      //document.getElementById("chatbot").innerHTML = dataText;
      //alert(dataText);
      var objDiv = document.getElementById("chatbotid");
      objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Cannot get data");
    }
  });
  //document.getElementById("chatbot").innerHTML = dataText;
  }
```

```css
body {
  color: #421;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #069597;
  background-image: url("girl.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

span {
  color: #104A70;
  padding: 1px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #104A70;
}

#main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  right: 60px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 0px solid #421;
  padding: 40px;
}

#main div {
  margin: 10px;
}

#input {
  border: 0;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #421;
  color: #104A70;
}

#line {
  text-align: center;
  background: #3BB2B4;
}

#chatbotid {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: rgb(230, 230, 225);
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #104A70;
}
```

```html
<div id="line">
  <hr/>
  <h1 style="color:rgb(255,255,255);"> Vawsum Help Desk</h1>
  <hr/>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <!-- <div> <span id="user"></span></div>  -->
  <!--I have deleted user from this line -->
  <div id="chatbotid"> <span id="chatbot"></span></div>
  <!--I have deleted chatbot from this line -->
  <div><input id="input" type="text" placeholder="say something..." autocomplete="off" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is super broad, and isn’t a code issue. It’s an implementation question. Do you know the difference between users on your side?

Comment: To differentiate between any two users on my side I can assign a unique user id to every user.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards Please answer this question, if you know the solution. I have to implement it in given time. 
If you can share a link that explains implementation to similiar problems ?

Answer (score 1):

When you make a connection with Watson Assistant, you get a conversation ID that comes back with the response.

You can use that to determine if two different users are talking at the same time.

---

Update based on comment:

Watson Assistant is stateless. It has no memory of previous calls.

When you return the context object you received, it will continue on from where it last left off. If you don't supply the conversation ID, or an invalid conversation id it will generate a new one.

Comment: my question is how Watson identifies that these APIs calls are requested by two different users. Because for all APIs call I am using the same credentials for Watson assistant.

Comment: If I am not wrong then every API call will have a different conversation ID. so we will have different conversation ids for the same users for different messages. (Correct me if I am saying anything wrong).

Comment: Updated based on comment.